# How do I clear notifications using ADB shell

Tags: android, shell, adb, android-notifications

I know I can unlock the screen, pull down the notifications, and press the clear notifications button, but there's got to be a way to clear the notifications through `ADB`, right? I'm guessing it's some `Intent` sent through the 'am' command, or maybe something even simpler, but I can't seem to find anything on the net. All I'm getting is `Java` code for use with an `apk`.

Edit: I should probably mention that I'm running on 4.3, sometimes commands may vary between versions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
adb shell service call notification 1
```

Comment: $ adb shell service call notification 1
Result: Parcel(fffffffc ffffffff   '........')

Comment: you need root to use `service` commands. other than that it should work in 4.3 no problem

Comment: thank you, accepted answer. Instead of restarting the device in root, I used su -c: adb shell su -c service call notification 1

Comment: @MishaP: It might just be me, but I think you have to wrap `service call notification 1` in quotes to make `su -c` work.

Answer (score 6):

If you know the type of the device and Android version, you can clear notifications using ADB without having rooted device.

The idea is to **pull down** notifications and **swipe away** all notifications one by one.

1. Pull down:

   ```
   adb shell input swipe 0 0 0 300
   ```
2. Swipe away:

   ```
   adb shell input swipe 0 400 300 400
   ```

> It is important to mention, that the (x,y) is something that vary between different type of devices and Android versions. You will need to find by several checks what is the best x,y for you.

#### The full script

```
adb shell input swipe 0 0 0 300
num=$(adb shell dumpsys notification | grep NotificationRecord | wc -l)
echo $num
while [ $num -gt 0 ]; do
    adb shell input swipe 0 400 300 400
    num=$(( $num - 1 ))
done
```

More details can be found here: https://www.sromku.com/blog/android-adb-clear-notifications

Comment: I've tried it and in my case it did not work, because not all notifications can be dismissed e.g. Android Wizard notification that might appear when starting the device for the first time. See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setOngoing(boolean)